# Xamarin.Forms and Snap.svg

Tags: svg, xamarin.forms, snap.svg

I will try to render some svg's in xamarin forms.

But the existing svg's are written in snap.svg.

Give it a nice why to render such svg's in xamarin forms?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Snap is used for animating svgs in web. You can't use the snap animations of svg in xamarin UI, because they are javascript animations. If you need just the svg, without the animation, you can export the inner svg (take a look [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/snapsvg/bhRiFn6jogw)) and then use [TwinTechs.SvgImage](https://www.nuget.org/packages/TwinTechsForms.SvgImage/) library for rendering cross-platform svgs in your xamarin.forms application.

**EDIT 1:**
You can load the svg into a WebView. I've created a sample project, which you can find [here](https://github.com/kyurkchyan/xamarin-samples/tree/master/SvgSample).

I've used XLabs's `HybridWebView` [control](https://github.com/XLabs/Xamarin-Forms-Labs/wiki/HybridWebView). It allows to load html into web view. The rest is straightforward. You need to add HTML folder to iOS and Android projects (root project directory and Assets directory respectively). For iOS you need to copy HTML directory manually as described in `HybridWebView` doc

```
HybridWebViewRenderer.CopyBundleDirectory("HTML");
```

Then in your xaml page you declare the web view

```
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:controls="clr-namespace:XLabs.Forms.Controls;assembly=XLabs.Forms"
             x:Class="SvgSample.Views.SvgPage"
             BackgroundColor="White">
  <controls:HybridWebView
    x:Name="webView"
    VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand"
    HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" />
</ContentPage>
```

And in xaml.cs file you need to load HTML into the web view in OnAppearing method (this is important, otherwise it will not work, again check out `HybridWebView` doc)

```
protected override void OnAppearing()
        {
            base.OnAppearing();
            webView.LoadFromContent("HTML/guage.html");
        }
```

I've tested for iOS and Android and it worked.

Comment: Our svg's are not animated. But complex calculated, do you think i can render this in a webview?

Comment: I wanted to write that, yes you can. But I don't think that's what you want. WebView is big object which uses a lot of memory and resources, and you definitely don't want to use it multiple times in a screen just to render svg. You should export them as svg and use svg custom renderers to render them on screen. One example, which I normally use in my apps is TwinTechs.SvgImage

Comment: I apprehend that, this is not the solution. The svg's are realy complex like an radial-gauge with needle. Thank you!

Comment: Can you upload the svg to somewhere. I'll try to help you out with that, and give example how to load that into a webview.